# How Change CurrentIndex from another Class Button

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have two classes; Class A with A-Ui->pushbutton and Class B with B-Ui->stackedWidget. I would like to change current index  (ui->stackedWidget->setcurrentIndex(2)) from class A when I released the pushbutton.

What I have tried so far:

I created a function in Class B.cpp and declared in "b.h" as public slots:

```
void B::updatepage(int index) {

ui->stackedWidget->setcurrentIndex(index);

}
```

and

Connected a signal to the pushbutton;

```
connect( ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(updatepage(2));
```

However, i did not get any error when I run app but I could not achieve what I wanted to do.

Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: `updatepage(2)` you can't supply a parameter this way. You could use a lambda or a  QSignalMapper to do this if the value of the parameter was not fixed. If the value is fixed then I believe the answer solves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that directly by using the `updatepage(2)`, what you can do is declaring the use of the function in the header with a default value, but this will always change to the second page:

Content of "a.h":

```
#include "b.h"
class A {
...
public slots:
    void updatepage(int index = 2);
public:
    void setBDialogWindow(B* bDialogWindow);
...
private:
B* m_bDialogWindow;
...
};
```

In the constructor of B add the initialization of `m_aDialogWindow` and the connection:

```
m_bDialogWindow = 0;
connect( ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(updatepage()));
```

and in the implementation ("a.cpp"):

```
void A::setBDialogWindow(B* bDialogWindow){
  m_bDialogWindow = bDialogWindow;
}

void A::updatepage(int index) {
  if ( m_bDialogWindow){
    m_bDialogWindow->ui->stackedWidget->setcurrentIndex(index);
  }
}
```

Also you need to change the access of ui in `B` to `public`, this is not a good practice and should be done via another method, but for the example is OK.

Finally, in main add after the declaration of B and before b.show() the following:

```
a.setBDialogWindow(&w);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it does not work. Even though i declared as you wrote in Class B, I got this error;QObject::connect: No such slot A:updatepage(),

Comment: The code you wrote is not enough to be understood, but from the error, it means that you are doing the connection in the class A and must be done in B, where the SLOT is declared. So the ui pointer you have to pass it to the class somehow... for example in the constructor of B...

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is so simple, I created two windows and main function just show these A window and B window. When I press the button from Window A, I want to change currentIndex situation of stackedWidget which is in Window B. I took the pictures of codes and window here. Maybe this is more clearified. Thanks                                               https://ibb.co/MctT5nz
https://ibb.co/wCyhVKK
https://ibb.co/y86dPk5
https://ibb.co/BLLwJHH

Comment: And your main??

Comment: My main is almost same when I created Project A, I just added show function for ClassB. link: https://ibb.co/cbYpr6z

Comment: @Gasteizko it worked after I add #include "b.h"
#include "ui_b.h" these libraries to a.cpp. Thank you so much! Which method would be more appropriate for better approach to the problem? As you see, I am new to qt creator and c++, I am willingly to learn practicing with different ways. thank you again!

Comment: It depends on the problem you want to solve, but in that case, maybe is a good idea to launch the window controller by the class of that window. but as i said, will depend on the problem.